# is this matrix invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Is the following matrix invertible?

$\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{1} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{x} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{2}}} & \cdots  & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{k}}}  \\
   \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{x} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{2}}} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{3}}} & \cdots  & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{k+1}}}  \\
   \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{2}}} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{3}}} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{4}}} & \cdots  & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{k+2}}}  \\
   \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots   \\
   \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{k}}} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{k+1}}} & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{k+2}}} & \cdots  & \sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{{{x}^{2k+2}}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: $\det=0$, it is not invertible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint.* Let $v_x=(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^k)^T$. Note that $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{k+1}$ are linearly independent, because the augmented matrix $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{k+1})$ is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Now your matrix is $A_n=\sum_{x=1}^n v_xv_x^T$. By considering quantities of the form $u^TA_nu$, it is easy to derive a necessary and sufficient condition for $A_n$ to be invertible.